# How to trigger script after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a form that that I think is using a event listener to know when a button is being clicked and then changes the form to the next fieldset.

I need to make an ajax call and then once complete to trigger this call but I can't work out how to do it.

The standard button is

```
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
```

And the script it is using is

```
<script id="rendered-js">
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function () {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

  //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

  //show the next fieldset
  next_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({ opacity: 0 }, {
    step: function (now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
      scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
      left = now * 50 + "%";
      //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
        'position': 'absolute' });

      next_fs.css({ 'left': left, 'opacity': opacity });
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function () {
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack' });

});

$(".previous").click(function () {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

  //de-activate current step on progressbar
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

  //show the previous fieldset
  previous_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({ opacity: 0 }, {
    step: function (now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
      scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
      left = (1 - now) * 50 + "%";
      //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({ 'left': left });
      previous_fs.css({ 'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')', 'opacity': opacity });
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function () {
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack' });

});

$(".submit").click(function () {
  return false;
});
```

I have changed the button to call an ajax query which is working fine

```
<input type="button" name="companyNameSearchButtonForm" id="companyNameSearchButtonForm"  class="next action-button" value="Search" onclick="companyNameSearch()"/>
```

But how can I get it to trigger then clicking of a next button after the ajax call has completed? I have tried to simulate the click etc but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to move the function out of the click event so then you can call them programmatically anywhere in your code and not rely on a click.

```
// form steps module
var formSteps = (function() {

  var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
  var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
  var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

  var next = function() {
    if (animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    //...snip
  }

  var previous = function() {
    if (animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    //...snip
  }

  return {
    next,
    previous
  }
})()

$(".next").click(formSteps.next);

$(".previous").click(formSteps.previous);

$(".submit").click(function() {
  return false;
});
```

Then in your `companyNameSearch` function you can call `formSteps.next()` after your ajax call.

Comment: sorry where do I declare the variables current_fs etc?

Comment: in the module, unless they are needed elsewhere ie. global but its not ideal you want to aim to group things/logic into modules etc.. sorry ill update and include them

Comment: thanks sorry not used a module before.do you I just place it all in a script tag?

Comment: there is other ways but the revealing module pattern is a common jquery pattern, which is easily moved into a plugin `$().whatnot()` so thought id add it, but you could just use global functions.

Comment: I think I must be doing something wrong. I have done as you suggested.

http://www.ehsandbox.com/OMZETGARANT/index.php

this is the page. If you click the next button it moves but if you click the search it jumps to the end of the progress bar but doesn't move the page

it seems it can't find the current set maybe?

Comment: looking at your source on the page, is dont see any attempt to do what ive suggested, basically you have to abstract out the function and then call them when you like., this is just basic javascript.